# How to adjust the gap between horizontal bars in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

How can I reduce the distance between horizontally placed bars in a chart? In this way, I will be able to save space in an article with a page limit. As an example, I prepared the following code and screenshot.

[image: The gaps I want to reduce are places in red.]

```
library(ggplot2)
survey <- data.frame(fruit=c("Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Pears"),
                     people=c(40, 50, 30, 15, 35, 20),tur=c("A","B","A","B","B","A"))
ggplot(survey, aes(x=fruit, y=people)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE,width = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~tur, ncol = 2,scales = "free")+
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: why not increasing the width such as `width = 0.9`?

Comment: @Roman If I reduce the space between them, I can make it smaller. I have to shrink it because of the page limit. There are several graphs like this. I can save a lot of space if I can. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `aspect.ratio` can help?

I suspect the issue might be due to the plotting area of the device rather than
ggplot, which seems to fill the device area.

With revised data using facet_wrap you are back to using `aspect.ratio`

```r
ggplot(survey1, aes(x = fruit, y = people)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, width = 0.9)+
  facet_wrap(~tur, ncol = 2, scales = "free")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.3)
```

[image]

Perhaps the issue is understanding how you transfer the plots into your article.

```r
ggsave("skinny_plot.png", width = 150, height = 40, units = "mm")

ggsave("skinny_plot.pdf", width = 150, height = 40, units = "mm")
```

Which gives you:

[image]

**data**

```
survey1 <- data.frame(fruit=c("Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Pears"),
                     people=c(40, 50, 30, 15, 35, 20),
                     tur=c("A","B","A","B","B","A"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your effort. I tried your suggestion. But "aspect.ratio" has shrunk the ratio down to scale. So when I adjust the shape to readable size, the gaps appear again. I have to reduce the gaps rather than shrink the shape completely. Thank you.

Comment: Try `coord_fixed`, in the edited answer, however, I suspect ggplot uses the full area available in the plotting device. May be the question should include the other graphs so the real problem of fitting multiple graphs on a page is reproducible.

Comment: Other figures are not on the same page. They are on other pages. But they have spaces like this in them. However, you are right, I have to give other information. I added this information and updated the codes and data again. When I use the "coord_fixed (1.5)" that you suggested here, I get 2 errors. 
`"Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error: coord_fixed doesn't support free scales "`
Actually "faced_wrap" does this problem. But I have to use it.

Comment: Sorry, your code does not work on the plot zoom screen. I don't know what else I can do. In the meantime, after asking this question, the message "You have reached your question limit" appeared. What could have happened?

Comment: Have you used the correct data? you need the `survey1` dataset at the end of the answer. I've just checked on my computer and the graph plots exactly as in the images in the answer. I'm not sure you should be changing the question.

Comment: Add `theme(aspect.ratio = 0.3)` and change `geom_col(..., width = 0.9` then the code in the question matches the code in the answer.

Comment: The code is working for `width = 0.9`. But it doesn't work for `width = 0.5`. I guess there is no way to make the bars smaller and the spacing smaller at the same time.

Comment: When I typed your code, it gave an error for "facet_wrap (~ tur, ncol = 2, scales =" free ")". I did not write this in the question because I thought it was not an important code. However, I added it later. I guess that's why the SO system restricted me. I guess it will take a few more years to understand SO. Thank you for everything.

Comment: What is the error? And if you can replicate the graphs in the answer, would this answer your question? You will not achieve closer spacing of the bars with `width = 0.5` because bar width and gaps between bars are controlled by this one argument. You would need two arguments to achieve what you wish.

Comment: What I said as a error was something that came out in the situation before the revision. You are right, I need two arguments. The best solution is your code. Thanks.